# Synchronizing local mysql database with remote one with a script or automatically?

Tags: mysql, xampp, synchronization

Is there a way to sync a MySQL database with a remote one either automatically or with a script? The data is not time sensitive, but I don't want to have to export it out of the local database and then import it into the remote one.

I am one Windows Vista and using XAMPP as my local stack.

Answer (score 3):

Replication works quite good, and it's not hard to configure. The official doc ([for 5.1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-howto.html)) it's easy to follow.